# Check there exists any number appears at least array.size()/4 times

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

Given an unsorted array but the same elements are adjacent to each other.
It is possible to check the array contains any element appearing at least array.size()/4 times?

Linear scan with a hash table is trivial, I am wondering is there any algorithm whose complexity is even better.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if such elements exists, then it means that if you check at `0`, `n/8`, `2n/8`, ... and `3n/4`, at least two times the same element shows up, then we can use binary search to find the bounds of that element, and check if it occurs the required amount.

Comment: I have to disagree with the marked duplication-  that question does not supply the condition that same elements are adjacent to each other, so an asymptopically faster algorithm exists for this question as @WillemVanOnsem describes.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I guess you started out suggesting multiples of n/4 to find a problem with rounding down - and missed one occurrence in changing to n/8. I hold that six probes at about 0, n/5, 2n/5, 3n/5, 4n/5 and n-1 are enough.

Comment: @greybeard: yes, that was a mistake, but I think the general idea still holds :)

Comment: This question really should not be marked as duplicate (relevant though), I explicitly mark it as the binary-search category to avoid people get mislead to think these two are the identical questions.

Answer (score 0):

If identical elements are always adjacent to each other just to a traversal and find the element with the maximum number of entries.
If the maximum is < array.size()/4 then no element satisfies your condition.
See below a sample java code with 2 while loops

```
int index=0, currentSize, maxSize = 0, currentElem;
while (index<array.length){
  currentElem = array[index];
  currentSize = 1;
  index++;
  while (index<array.length && currentElem==array[index]){
   currentSize++;
   index++;
  }

  if (maxSize<currentSize) {
    maxSize = currentSize;
  }
}

if (maxSize>=array.length/4) return "Yes";
else return "No";
```